# Have multiple plugins use redux-framework for options page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

Can I have multiple plugins use single instance of Redux framework to provide multiple options page?

I am writing 2 plugins, for which I will be using Redux framework to provide options, can I have one Redux framework and make my plugins create 2 separate options forms?

Answer (score 0):

Used the [Redux builder](http://build.reduxframework.com) with Suggest+Embed option, which basically has the entire Redux plugin embedded in the plugin files it generates and won't conflict with other plugin's redux framework.

Also, you just need to maintain your own global variable and you can have conflict free setup with multiple plugins creating multiple forms using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just use different opt_names and you can have as many panels running as you want.

For plugins, be sure to wait until Plugins Loaded before you include the Redux framework.php file, and then instantiate your options.  :)